# aggregate data frame with many columns according to one column

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

From a data frame of many columns, I would like to aggregate (i.e. `sum`) hundreds of columns by a single column, without specifying each of the column names.

Some sample data:

```
names <- floor(runif(20, 1, 5))
sample <- cbind(names)

for(i in 1:20){
col <- rnorm(20,2,4)
sample <- cbind(sample, col)
}
```

What I have until now is the following code, but it gives me that arguments must be the same length.

```
aggregated <- aggregate.data.frame(sample[,c(2:20)], by = as.list(names),     FUN = 'sum')
```

Original dataset is a lot bigger, so I can't specify the name of each of the columns to be aggregated and I can't use the list function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to list them at all:

```
aggregate(. ~ names, sample, sum) # . represents all other columns
```

Of course base R is my favorite but in case someone wants `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(sample) %>% 
             group_by(names) %>% 
             summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just alter your code slightly:

`aggregated <- aggregate(sample[,c(2:20)], by = list(names),     FUN = 'sum')`